# Uncaught Error: Invalid template: Kendo Ui Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

What could be Causing This kind of error in KendoGrid when i add Conditions in the Template it says Invalid Template

I read and followed the instructions in adding Conditions and i think what i did was right

This is my code inside the Template

```
   # if (${ LogicalDelete } == false) { #  
      <ul class="top-btns" style="float:right;" >   
      <a class="btn btn-gray fa fa-plus" id=btnApply${ID}></a>
      </ul>
    # } else { #  
         <ul class="top-btns" style="float:right;" >
         <a class="btn btn-gray fa fa-minus" id=btnApply${ID}></a>
         </ul>
           # } #
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably needed quotes around your `id` attributes. Also, (and I'm not 100% on this) the `${}` syntax might have something to do with it as well. Try this:

```
# if (LogicalDelete === false) { #  
  <ul class="top-btns" style="float:right;" >   
    <a class="btn btn-gray fa fa-plus" id="btnApply#=ID#"></a>
  </ul>
# } else { #  
  <ul class="top-btns" style="float:right;" >
    <a class="btn btn-gray fa fa-minus" id="btnApply#=ID#"></a>
  </ul>
# } #
```